# I want to know something about pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

p is pointer on a array

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *p = array;
```

And when i want to printf the array entries:

is this the same and why:

- `*(p++)`
- `*p++`

Hope you can help me!

Comment: You need to read about operator precedence.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I want to know why its the same thing

Comment: See the comment above - operator precedence

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: The issue is also to understand what "arrays decay into pointers" mean - this is more tricky than operator precedence -, and that requires a chapter of some good C programming book so is too broad for some SO answer.

Comment: yes, but is it the same as `(*p)++`?

Comment: No. (*p)++ will access to the variable pointed by p, then increment it. *(p++) and *p++, which are the same things, increment the address pointed by p, then reach the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

++ has a higher precedence (meaning it binds to p tighter) than *
therefore `*p++` is equivalent to `*(p++)`.

Something similar to this is the difference between `*p[]` and `(*p)[]`.
`[]` has a higher precedence than `*` therefore `*p[]` is equivalent to `*(p[])` which makes a `list a pointers` but something like `(*p)[]` explicitly says to do whats in the brackets first making in this case a `pointer to a list` (mind blowing)